# Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a detail pages which has the ids, but if i don't pass id in http://mysite.com/Detail?id=131 or if I just type http://mysite.com/Detail i get the error

```
Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference
```

i want to show custom error message on this, how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may make `id` parameter nullable and check it in action like this:

```
public ActionResult Detail(int? id)
{
  if (id.HasValue() == false)
  { return custom error message }
}
```

Or you may annotate your nullable id with `[Required(ErrorMessage = "error message")]` to get client validation as well. And perform server validation like:

```
public ActionResult Detail(int? id)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid == false)
  { return custom error message }
}
```